# where clause in LEFT OUTER JOIN is not being evaluated

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I need to show aggregate counts of behavior incidents from multiple tables based on Month. Most critically, I need to show months even when the count is 0. I created a Months table to store that data, then Joined to the behavior/student tables to get the counts. One of  my Left Outer Join clauses is being ignored though, and I can't figure out why:

```
SELECT ISNULL(i5_btincident.syr, '1617') AS 'SchoolYear'
    ,m.MonthNumber
    ,Count(i5_btincident.incident_id) AS 'Incidentct'
    ,m.sortorder
    ,m.MonthName
FROM Months m
LEFT OUTER JOIN i5_btincident i5_btincident 
    ON m.MonthNumber = month(i5_btincident.incident_date)
        AND i5_btincident.sch = '310'
        AND i5_btincident.dst = '002'
        AND i5_btincident.syr = '1617'
--and i5_btincident.positive_or_negative like :f1_RB_Behavior.BehCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN i5_btstupart i5_btstupart 
    ON (i5_btincident.syr = i5_btstupart.syr)
        AND (i5_btincident.incident_ID = i5_btstupart.incident_ID)
        AND (i5_btincident.dst = i5_btstupart.dst)
        AND (i5_btincident.sch = i5_btstupart.sch)
LEFT OUTER JOIN i5_student 
    ON i5_student.syr = i5_btstupart.syr
        AND i5_student.attend_dst = i5_btstupart.dst
        AND i5_student.attend_sch = i5_btstupart.sch
        AND i5_student.stuid = i5_btstupart.stuid
        AND i5_student.is_active = 'Y'
LEFT OUTER JOIN i5_grad_status i5_grad_status 
    ON i5_student.syr = i5_grad_status.syr
        AND i5_student.attend_dst = i5_grad_status.dst
        AND i5_student.attend_sch = i5_grad_status.sch
        AND i5_student.stuid = i5_grad_status.stuid
GROUP BY i5_btincident.syr
    ,m.MonthNumber
    ,m.sortOrder
    ,m.MonthName
ORDER BY m.sortorder
```

The **and i5_student.is_active = 'Y'** in my left outer join to i5_btstudent is being ignored... why?

Working sample update:

```
CREATE TABLE LRB_student (
stuid tinyint,
name varchar(10),
dst varchar(3),
sch varchar(3),
syr varchar(4),
is_active varchar(1)
);
go

CREATE TABLE LRB_btincident (
incid tinyint,
descr varchar(10),
dst varchar(3),
sch varchar(3),
syr varchar(4),
incdate datetime
);
go

CREATE TABLE LRB_btstupart (
incid tinyint,
stuid tinyint,
dst varchar(3),
sch varchar(3),
syr varchar(4),
);
go

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Months](
[SortOrder] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[MonthNumber] [nchar](2) NOT NULL,
[MonthName] [nchar](12) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO

INSERT INTO LRB_student VALUES(1,'student1','001','002','1617','Y');
INSERT INTO LRB_student VALUES(2,'student2','001','002','1617','Y');
INSERT INTO LRB_student VALUES(3,'student3','001','002','1617','N');
INSERT INTO LRB_student VALUES(4,'student4','001','002','1617','Y');
INSERT INTO LRB_student VALUES(5,'student5','001','002','1617','Y');
INSERT INTO LRB_student VALUES(6,'student6','001','002','1617','N');
INSERT INTO LRB_student VALUES(7,'student7','001','002','1617','Y');
go

INSERT INTO LRB_btincident VALUES(10,'Cheating','001','002','1617','2016-09-01 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO LRB_btincident VALUES(11,'Assault','001','002','1617','2016-10-01 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO LRB_btincident VALUES(12,'Technology','001','002','1617','2016-11-01 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO LRB_btincident VALUES(13,'PDA','001','002','1617','2016-12-01 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO LRB_btincident VALUES(14,'Tardies','001','002','1617','2017-01-01 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO LRB_btincident VALUES(15,'Cheating','001','002','1617','2017-02-01 00:00:00.000');
```

go

```
INSERT INTO LRB_btstupart VALUES(10,1,'001','002','1617');
INSERT INTO LRB_btstupart VALUES(11,1,'001','002','1617');
INSERT INTO LRB_btstupart VALUES(12,3,'001','002','1617');
INSERT INTO LRB_btstupart VALUES(12,5,'001','002','1617');
INSERT INTO LRB_btstupart VALUES(13,4,'001','002','1617');
INSERT INTO LRB_btstupart VALUES(14,5,'001','002','1617');
INSERT INTO LRB_btstupart VALUES(15,6,'001','002','1617');
go

INSERT INTO Months VALUES(1,'08','August');
INSERT INTO Months VALUES(2,'09','September');
INSERT INTO Months VALUES(3,'10','October');
INSERT INTO Months VALUES(4,'11','November');
INSERT INTO Months VALUES(5,'12','December');
INSERT INTO Months VALUES(6,'01','January');
INSERT INTO Months VALUES(7,'02','February');
INSERT INTO Months VALUES(8,'03','March');

 SELECT 
  ISNULL(lrb_btincident.syr,'1617') as 'SchoolYear',
  m.MonthNumber,
  COUNT(lrb_btincident.incid) as 'Incidentct',
  m.sortorder,
  m.MonthName
FROM Months m
  LEFT OUTER JOIN lrb_btincident lrb_btincident ON m.MonthNumber = month    (lrb_btincident.incdate) AND lrb_btincident.sch = '002'
      AND lrb_btincident.dst = '001'
      AND lrb_btincident.syr = '1617'

  LEFT OUTER JOIN lrb_btstupart lrb_btstupart ON (lrb_btincident.syr = lrb_btstupart.syr) 
    AND (lrb_btincident.incID = lrb_btstupart.incID) 
    AND (lrb_btincident.dst = lrb_btstupart.dst) 
    AND (lrb_btincident.sch = lrb_btstupart.sch)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN lrb_student ON lrb_student.syr = lrb_btstupart.syr 
    AND lrb_student.dst = lrb_btstupart.dst 
    AND lrb_student.sch = lrb_btstupart.sch 
    AND lrb_student.stuid = lrb_btstupart.stuid 
    AND lrb_student.is_active = 'N'  -- this is being ignored
 GROUP BY 
   lrb_btincident.syr,
       m.MonthNumber,
       m.sortOrder,
       m.MonthName
 ORDER BY m.sortorder
```

SOLUTION (Sorry about the formatting - just trying to get it out there):

```
WITH MnthInc(Year,SortOrder,Month,Count)
AS
(
select i5_btincident.syr as "SchoolYear",
   case month(i5_btincident.incident_date)
        when 8 then 1
        when 9 then 2
        when 10 then 3
        when 11 then 4
        when 12 then 5
        when 1 then 6
        when 2 then 7
        when 3 then 8
        when 4 then 9
        when 5 then 10
        when 6 then 11
        when 7 then 12
        else 0
   end "MonthSort",
   datename(month,i5_btincident.incident_date) as "IncidentMonth",
   Count( i5_btincident.incident_id ) as "IncidentCt"
  from ( i5_btincident i5_btincident
   inner join i5_btstupart i5_btstupart on (i5_btincident.syr = i5_btstupart.syr) and (i5_btincident.incident_ID = i5_btstupart.incident_ID) and (i5_btincident.dst = i5_btstupart.dst) and (i5_btincident.sch = i5_btstupart.sch) )
   --inner join evi_User_Table evi_User_Table on (i5_btstupart.stuid = evi_User_Table.stuid) and (i5_btstupart.syr = evi_User_Table.syr)
inner join i5_student on i5_student.syr = i5_btstupart.syr and i5_student.attend_dst = i5_btstupart.dst and i5_student.attend_sch = i5_btstupart.sch and i5_student.stuid = i5_btstupart.stuid
left join i5_grad_status i5_grad_status on i5_student.syr = i5_grad_status.syr and i5_student.attend_dst =  i5_grad_status.dst and i5_student.attend_sch =  i5_grad_status.sch and i5_student.stuid = i5_grad_status.stuid
where i5_btincident.sch = '310'
   and i5_btincident.dst = '002'
   and i5_btincident.syr = '1617'
   and i5_btincident.positive_or_negative like 'N%'
group by i5_btincident.syr,
    case month(i5_btincident.incident_date)
        when 8 then 1
        when 9 then 2
        when 10 then 3
        when 11 then 4
        when 12 then 5
        when 1 then 6
        when 2 then 7
        when 3 then 8
        when 4 then 9
        when 5 then 10
        when 6 then 11
        when 7 then 12
        else 0
   end,
   datename(month,i5_btincident.incident_date)
)
Select Months.SortOrder,Months.MonthName as 'IncidentMonth',ISNULL(MnthInc.Count,0) as 'IncidentCt'
from Months
LEFT OUTER JOIN MnthInc on MnthInc.SortOrder = Months.SortOrder AND MnthInc.Month = Months.MonthName
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: why do you think it's being ignored?

Comment: are you getting records in your results from that table that are not null, but the is_Active = 'y'?

Comment: I have no idea... If I put it in a "where" clause, then I don't get all the rows from the months table like I need...but I get the right students. Seems like I should be able to get all the rows from my right table and be able to limit my rows from the left...

Comment: You don't have any idea why you think it's being ignored. Stick `is_Active` from that tablei n your SELECT and I'll bet you don't get any 'Y' values in there.

Comment: remove the group by and check what columns are joined. add `SELECT *`

Comment: If you put any of the criteria into the where part, it will turn your outer join into inner join.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: If I add is_Active  to the select clause, then I have to add it to the group by, and I get weird results.  I did a Select * (removed the aggregate and group by). I am getting data from Months With NULL for all data from other tables for August, May, June, April (there are no incidents in those months)  For a few records, I have data from Months, i5_btincident, then NULLS for btstupart, student, and grad_status (ie, we have incidents out there without students attached) and so on....

Comment: I have a strong feeling you shouldn't be doing all outer joins

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen if I do inner joins, I lose the months where there is no data... I need to have those 0 months because the product I'm working with (Argos) seems to have a hard time reconciling comparison bar graphs where we might have data in August for schoolyear 1516 but not for schoolyear 1617. It wants to compare August 1516 with September 1617... no bueno.

Comment: @LauraBryngelson Dont post that in the comments, tampoco bueno. Just update your question with the aditional info.

Comment: You can try [**REXTESTER**](http://rextester.com/QQF87471) to prepare a working sample.